# pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction failed to extract the first cluster

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, pcl

I'm trying to extract the first cluster from point cloud. Here is my code

Input

```
cluster_pcd_ptr
tolerance
```

body

```
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cluster_tree(
    new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
cluster_tree->setInputCloud(cluster_pcd_ptr);

std::vector<pcl::PointIndices> cluster_indices;
pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction<pcl::PointXYZ> ec;
ec.setClusterTolerance(tolerance);
ec.setSearchMethod(cluster_tree);
ec.setInputCloud(cluster_pcd_ptr);
ec.extract(cluster_indices);

pcl::PointIndices::Ptr patch_indices_ptr(new pcl::PointIndices);
patch_indices_ptr->header = cluster_indices[0].header;
patch_indices_ptr->indices = cluster_indices[0].indices;

pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> patch_extract;
patch_extract.setInputCloud(cluster_pcd_ptr);
patch_extract.setIndices(patch_indices_ptr);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr patch_pcd_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
patch_extract.filter(*patch_pcd_ptr);
```

But I always got the access violation reading location error at `patch_extract.filter(*patch_pcd_ptr)`. So what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger or similar, to find out where the access violation comes from exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a problem with your code.I have tested your code and it runs normally. you can add judgement to judge the size of 'patch_indices_ptr' or the size of 'cluster_pcd_ptr' is zero or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).